# loop-free operations on two-dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This may seem a silly question to the community, but I didn't manage to find an answer online. Imagine one has a situation like this:

```
area_vector = np.zeros(np.shape(normal))
for i in range(len(area)):
    area_vector[i] = area[i] * normal[i]
```

`normal` is a N x 3 array and `area` a 1D array of size N. As we can see, the loop is essentially an operation over rows of two-dimensional numpy arrays (`area_vector` and `normal`).

Is it possible to perform the above calculation in just 1 line (i.e. avoiding the `for` loop and using numpy's built-in methods as much as possible)?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Please provide minimal example of the input arrays for clarity (is "Nx1" a 2D array?)

Comment: You might want to edit out `pressure` from your example, as it is not really relevant. In the for loop, you can e.g. replace it with `len(area)` or `len(normal)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
import numpy as np
N = np.random.randint(10, 100)
normal = np.random.random((N, 3))
pressure = np.random.random((N, 1))
area = np.random.random((N, 1))
area_vector = np.zeros(np.shape(normal))
for i in range(len(pressure)):
    area_vector[i] = area[i] * normal[i]

area_vector_alternative = area * normal
print((area_vector_alternative == area_vector).all())
```

prints

```
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael for your reply. Now I see what I was doing wrong: `pressure` and `area` had shape (N,), what leads to an error (`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes`). If they have instead shape (N, 1), it works. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, (N,) != (N, 1) indeed